# Listen to new document additions Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an app that will listen to new document addition to Firestore collection. I have tried look at Firestore documentation, but doesn't work for my specific problem.
Here is my code listen to document updata

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users/" + companyID + "/trips").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                return;
            }
            if (!querySnapshot.isEmpty()){
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot qds : querySnapshot){
                    tripList.add(qds.getId());
                }
                showTripList();//update trip list view
            }
        }
    });
```

Show the list to the ListView

```
public void showTripList() {
    ListView tripListView = findViewById(R.id.tripList);

    if (tripList.size() != 0) {
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tripList);
        tripListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);//show trip list on screen
    } else {
        TextView noTripTxt = findViewById(R.id.noTripTxt);
        noTripTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//show "no trip has been made yet" text to user
    }
}
```

The logcat shows NullPointerException at this two line

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users/" + companyID + "/trips").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>()
tripList.add(qds.getId());
```

Comment: Description like "no luck" and "doesn't work" are really vague, and make it hard to help. What happens when you run this code? Specifically: if you run it in the debugger and step through it, what line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code that is work for me

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users/" + companyID + "/trips")
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                            return;
                        }
                        tripList.clear();//clear the ArrayList, because this method get all the document id instead of
                                        //the one that just created
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : value) {
                            if (doc.getId() != null){
                                tripList.add(doc.getId());//store the document IDs to ArrayList

                                Log.d(TAG, "Retrieved data: " + doc.getId());
                            }
                        }
                        showTripList();//show trip name to listView
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared seems to try and listen to the `trips` subcollection of a specific `companyId`. But the way you build the path to that collection seems suspicious:

```
collection("users" + companyID + "trips")
```

The total path should be `users/${companyID}/trips`, so it's more likely that the code should be:

```
collection("users/" + companyID + "/trips")
```

Without the `/` your code is listening to a top-level collection `users${companyID}trips`, which doesn't exist. So that would explain why you're not getting any results.

Note that you can easily prevent such string concatenation problems, by using the more explicit API variant:

```
collection("users").doc(companyID).collection("trips")
```

While that last variant is a bit longer, it removes the chance of making simple string concatenation mistakes.

---

With the collection path fixed, your code will be listening for the data in a subcollection. So it will match multiple documents, and get a `QuerySnapshot` as shown in the documentation on [listening to multiple documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to add "/" in the question because i'm trying many different code, i have update the question